# CSS problem with Chrome rendering strange things

Tags: html, css, web, menu, menuitem

Good day! The problem appears with actual Chrome version I already have.
This is the actual Chrome version I have 99.0.4844.51
Suddenly discovered that menus (we uses simple downloaded several years before with some style change) on our website go now wrong, for example that there is no font highlight (change colors) on menu hover
Before it was:

```
nav ul li:hover { 
    color: white; /* color menu active font */
    background: #005DAB;
    }
```

Now it doesn't work and was implemented also additional:

```
nav ul li a:hover {
    color: white;
    }
```

To make it highlighted as before.
I'm attaching complete [JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Precitools/hcf2dapw/21/) with code

But together with it appeared other very strange story - disappearing of menu buttons after hover. Because probably it cannot show in other browsers I made [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2YqlyHpftzg&ab_channel=PRECITOOLS) to show completely.

I'm sorry but I don't know where is the mistake and what to do. Your assistance is kindly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I think issue is happening in menu items which has children. You can try this css if it works:

```
@media (min-width:761px){ 
    li.sub:hover a, li:hover a {
        color: white !important;
    }
    li.sub ul a:hover {
        color: #005DAB !important;
    }
    li a{
      color: grey !important;
    }
}
@media (max-width:760px){ 
    li.sub:hover ul a {
        color: white !important;
    }
    li:hover a {
        color: #005DAB !important;
    }
    li.sub ul a:hover {
        color: #005DAB !important;
    }
    li.sub a:hover {
    color: #005DAB !important;
    }
    li a {
      color: white !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are correct, it works and helps from menu header disappering. Now fiddle is https://jsfiddle.net/Precitools/hcf2dapw/25/  Would you be so kind to help me to notice what could be done to make submenu hover font to blue without touching the header (for example for Submenu 1 and no touching Menu 2. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Precitools I've updated the answer please check if it works.

Comment: Thank you! All is perfect with widescreen. The max.width 760 with same mistakes... I implemented the same for small screen but doesn't work good. My real problem - I can't understand how to divide separate styles from header and submenu of it.  For example Menu2 is connected with Submenu 1. I touched Submenu 1, Menu 2 became unhovered but active as tree header but I cannot make separate color for it. Maybe you can leave small comments if possible... https://jsfiddle.net/Precitools/hcf2dapw/42/

Comment: @Precitools updated answer. If it helps you then please upvote and tick it.

Comment: Everything works. One more time thank you very much. I can't upvote because reputation is low but I will return to vote as soon as I can do any vote...